# two forms on the same page, unable to POST changes when both exist

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, tabs

First post so be gentle :) I've spent many hours getting my basic crud functions working. I can create, read, update and delete. YAY!

But when I have a second form on another tab - it doesn't work :(

I have tried to base as much of this on template functions as I can, so the two tabs are running the exact same code.

In fact, if I delete the content of the first tab - the form on the second tab starts working perfectly. So i'm thinking its something that should be unique to each form that isn't.

So to the code... Each tab has its own php. Clients.php and Contacts.php

```
﻿<?PHP //clients.php               

showTable(client,'Clients',true);

echo "<center><div class=\"btn-group\">\n";
echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-success\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#client_add\">Add</button>\n";
echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary UpdateButton\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-source=\"client\" data-table=\"table_client\" data-ID=\"1\" data-OrgID=\"".$orgid."\" data-target=\"#client_modify\">Modify</button>";
echo "<button type=\"button\" value=\"Delete\" class=\"btn btn-danger delButton\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-table=\"table_client\" data-ID=\"1\" data-OrgID=\"".$orgid."\" data-target=\"#client_del\">Delete</button>";
echo "</div></center>";
echo "</form>";
displayModals('client');
?>

﻿<?PHP    // contacts.php           
showTable(contact,'Contacts',true);

echo "<center><div class=\"btn-group\">\n";
echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-success\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#contact_add\">Add</button>\n";
echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary UpdateButton\"  data-source=\"contact\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-table=\"table_contact\" data-ID=\"1\" data-OrgID=\"".$orgid."\" data-target=\"#contact_modify\">Modify</button>";
echo "<button type=\"button\" value=\"Delete\" class=\"btn btn-danger delButton\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-table=\"table_contact\" data-ID=\"1\" data-OrgID=\"".$orgid."\" data-target=\"#contact_del\">Delete</button>";
echo "</div></center>";
echo "</form>";
displayModals('contact');
}?>
```

The below includes the displayModals function, my Jquery for the button clicks, and the showForm and showTable functions:

```
function displayModals($table){
echo "<div id=\"".$table."_add\" class=\"modal fade\" role=\"dialog\">\n";
echo "  <div class=\"modal-dialog\">\n";
echo "    <div class=\"modal-content\">\n";
echo "      <div class=\"modal-header\">\n";
echo "        <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">×</button>\n";
echo "        <h4 class=\"modal-title\">Add ".ucfirst($table)."</h4>\n";
echo "      </div>\n";
echo "      <div class=\"modal-body\">\n";
            showForm ($table,ucfirst($table)."s");
echo "      </div>\n";
echo "      <div class=\"modal-footer\">\n";
echo "        <a href=\"javascript: document.getElementById('f".$table."').submit()\" class=\"btn btn-success\">Save</a>\n";
echo "        <a href=\"#\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">Close</a>\n";
echo "      </div>\n";
echo "    </div>\n";
echo "  </div>\n";
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id=\"".$table."_modify\" class=\"modal fade\" role=\"dialog\">\n";
echo "  <div class=\"modal-dialog\">\n";
echo "    <div class=\"modal-content modify-content\">\n";
echo "      <div class=\"modal-header\">\n";
echo "        <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">×</button>\n";
echo "        <h4 class=\"modal-title\">Modify ".ucfirst($table)."</h4>\n";
echo "      </div>\n";
echo "      <div class=\"modal-body\">\n";
echo "      </div>\n";
echo "      <div class=\"modal-footer\">\n";
echo "        <a href=\"javascript: document.forms.f".$table."_modify.submit()\" class=\"btn btn-success\">Save</a>\n";
echo "        <a href=\"#\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">Close</a>\n";
echo "      </div>\n";
echo "    </div>\n";
echo "  </div>\n";
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id=\"".$table."_del\" class=\"modal fade\" role=\"dialog\">\n";
echo "  <div class=\"modal-dialog\">\n";
echo "    <div class=\"modal-content modify-content\">\n";
echo "      <div class=\"modal-header\">\n";
echo "        <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">×</button>\n";
echo "        <h4 class=\"modal-title\">Delete ".ucfirst($table)."</h4>\n";
echo "      </div>\n";
echo "      <div class=\"modal-body\">\n";
echo "      </div>\n";
echo "      <div class=\"modal-footer\">\n";
echo "        <a href=\"javascript: document.forms.table_del_".$table.".submit()\" class=\"btn btn-success\">Yes</a>\n";
echo "        <a href=\"#\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">No</a>\n";
echo "      </div>\n";
echo "    </div>\n";
echo "  </div>\n";
echo "</div>";
?>
<script>
$('.UpdateButton').click(function(){
       selected = [];
       var tab=$(this).attr('data-table');
        $.each($("#"+tab+" input[name='checkbox[]']:checked"), function(){            
         selected.push($(this).val());
       });

       if (selected.length===1) {
       var Id=$(this).attr('data-ID');
       var OrgId=$(this).attr('data-OrgID');
       var chkBox=selected[0];
       var table=$(this).attr('data-source');
        $.ajax({url:"../functions/form-edit-ajax.php?table="+table+"&chkBox="+chkBox+"&OrgID="+OrgId+"&Id="+Id,cache:false,success:function(result){
            $(".modify-content .modal-body").html(result);
        }});
        } else { $(".modify-content .modal-body").html("Please select one record to modify."); };
    delete selected;
    });

$('.delButton').click(function(){
        var table=$(this).attr('data-table');
        var data = $("#"+table).serialize();    
        $.ajax({
            url: "../functions/form-edit-ajax.php", // link of your "whatever" php
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            data: data, // all data will be passed here
            success: function(data){ 
                 $(".modify-content .modal-body").html(data); // The data that is echoed from the ajax.php
            }
        });
    });
</script><?PHP
}
?>

function showTable($table=NULL,$tabname=NULL,$sel=NULL,$rows=NULL) {
    $connection = dbConnect();
        $excludes = array("id", "org_id", "client_id", "status");
        //if ($rows) {die(print_r($rows));};
    //echo "<div class=\"container\">\n";
        echo ("</br></br>");               
        echo "<form action=\"/functions/form-edit.php";
        if ($rows) echo "?act=delete";
        echo "\" method=\"post\" id=\"table_";
        if ($rows) echo "del_";       
        echo $table."\" class=\"form-horizontal\">\n";
    /* show tables */
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, 'SHOW TABLES') or die('cannot show tables');
    if (!$table) {
        while($tableName = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

            $table = $tableName[0];
            echo "  <h3>",$table,"</h3>\n";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM '.$table) or die('cannot show columns from '.$table);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result2)) {         
            echo "  <table class=\"table table-striped\">\n";
            echo "    <thead>\n";
                    echo " <tr>\n";
                        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($result2)) {
                            echo '<th>',$row2[0],'</th>';
                        }
                    echo "</tr>\n";
                echo "  </thead>\n";
            }

                        if (!$rows) {
                            $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT * FROM '.$table) or die('cannot show data from '.$table);
                        } else {
                            $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE id IN ('.implode(",",$rows).')') or die('cannot show data from '.$table);
                        }
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result2)) {         
                echo "    <tbody>\n";
                echo "      <tr>\n";
                        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($result2);
                        foreach ($row2 as $row) {
                            echo '<td>',$row,'</td>';
                        }
                    echo "    </tr>\n";
                echo "    </tbody>\n";
            }
            echo "  </table>\n";
        }  // END OF WHILE LOOP
    }
    else {
                        if ($tabname) { echo "  <h3>",$tabname,"</h3>\n"; } else { echo "  <h3>",$table,"</h3>\n"; };
                        $org=$_SESSION[userData][org_id];
            $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM '.$table) or die('cannot show columns from '.$table);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {         
            echo "  <table class=\"table table-striped\">\n";
            echo "    <thead>\n";
                    echo "      <tr>\n";
                        if (!$rows) {
                                                    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($result2)) {
                                                        if (!in_array($row2[0], $excludes)) {
                                                            echo '<th>',ucwords(preg_replace( '/_+/', ' ', $row2[0])),'</th>';
                                                        } 
                                                    }
                                                } else { echo '<th>Title</th>';};
                                                if ($sel=='1') { echo ('<th>Select</th>'); };
                    echo "      </tr>\n";
                echo "    </thead>\n";
            }
                        mysqli_free_result($result2);

                        if (!$rows) {
                            $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE org_id='.$_SESSION[userData][org_id]) or die('cannot show data from '.$table);
                        } else {
                            $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT title,id FROM '.$table.' WHERE org_id='.$_SESSION[userData][org_id].' AND id IN ('.implode(",",$rows).');') or die('cannot show data from '.$table);
                        }

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {         
                echo "    <tbody>\n";
                                    foreach ($result2 as $row) {
                                        foreach ($excludes as $exc) {
                                            if ($exc=='id') {$row_id=$row[$exc];};
                                            unset($row[$exc]);
                                        }
                                        echo "      <tr>\n";
                                        mysqli_fetch_field($result2);
                                        foreach ($row as $element) {
                                                    echo ("<td>".$element."</td>");
                                        }
                                        if ($sel) {echo ('<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="'.$row_id.'"></td>');};
                                        if ($rows) {echo ('<input type="hidden" name="checkbox[]" value="'.$row_id.'">');};

                                    echo "      </tr>\n";                                        
                                    unset ($row_id);
                                    }
                echo "    </tbody>\n";
            }   
                        mysqli_free_result($result2);
                    echo ("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"table\" value=\"$table\">");
        echo "  </table>\n";
    }
       // echo "</form>";   
       // echo "</div>";
}
function showForm($table=NULL,$tabname=NULL,$orgid=NULL,$rec=NULL) {
    $connection = dbConnect();
        $excludes = array("id", "org_id", "client_id", "status");        

    if ($table) {
            echo "<form action=\"/functions/form-edit.php";
            if ($rec) {echo "?act=update"; };
            echo "\" method=\"post\" id=\"f".$table;
            if ($rec) {echo "_modify"; };
            echo "\" class=\"form-horizontal\">\n";

            $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM '.$table) or die('cannot show columns from '.$table);
            if ($rec) {
                $record = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT * from '.$table.' WHERE org_id='.$orgid.' AND id='.$rec.' LIMIT 1');
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($record, MYSQLI_BOTH);
            }
            $results3=array();
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result2)) {         
                    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($result2)) {   
                        foreach ($excludes as $exc) {
                            if ($row2[0]==$exc) {array_push($results3, $row2[0]); unset ($row2[0]);};
                        }            
                        if ($row2[0]) {
                            echo "  <div class=\"form-group\">\n";
                            echo "    <label class=\"control-label col-sm-3\" for=\"".$row2[0]."\">".ucwords(preg_replace( '/_+/', ' ', $row2[0])).":</label>\n";
                            echo "    <div class=\"col-sm-9\">\n";
                            if ($rec) {
                                if (is_array($row) && array_key_exists($row2[0],$row)) {
                                    echo "      <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"".$row2[0]."\" value=\"".$row[$row2[0]]."\" placeholder=\"Enter ".ucwords(preg_replace( '/_+/', ' ', $row2[0]))."\">\n";
                                 }
                            } else {
                                    echo "      <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"".$row2[0]."\" placeholder=\"Enter ".ucwords(preg_replace( '/_+/', ' ', $row2[0]))."\">\n";
                                 }
                            echo "    </div>\n";
                            echo "  </div>\n";                        
                        }
                    }

                    foreach ($results3 as $element) {
                        echo ("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"".$element."\" value=\"".$row[$element]."\">");
                    }
                    echo ("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"table\" value=\"$table\">");
            }       
            echo "</form>";
        }  // END OF WHILE LOOP

    else {
        echo "  <h3>No form selected</h3></br><h4>table=".$table."</br>\n";
    }
    unset($result2);
    unset($result3);
    unset ($row,$element,$table,$row2,$record);

}
```

So on the first tab with the Clients, I can add/modify/delete without any trouble. On the second tab, I can add and delete, but modify just seems to submit the unedited fields back to the database.

Oddly if I wipe out the contents of clients.php for testing, the second tab works perfectly? I can't help thinking its some sort of duplication somewhere that needs to be made unique.

Any pointers or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks everybody :)

Comment: Anybody able to help shed some light on this?